# LocalStorage is not working on Firefox. Getting Security error

Tags: angular, firefox, local-storage

I'm trying to store some information in browser local storage. My code works **fine** on **Chrome** However, i'm getting security error  and following warnings on Firefox and Safari

Firefox Version : 63.0.1 (64-bit)

Error and warning while retrieving data from local storage : 
[image]

**StackTrace :**

```
ERROR DOMException: "The operation is insecure." EventDetailsComponent.html:1
View_EventDetailsComponent_0
EventDetailsComponent.html:1 proxyClass compiler.js:17129
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/DebugContext_.prototype.logError
core.js:20684
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError
core.js:12632
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<
core.js:14878:54
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke
zone.js:388
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run
zone.js:138
```

**Error Msg :**

```
[WDS] Disconnected! vendor.js:157169:5 close

ERROR DOMException: "The operation is insecure." EventDetailsComponent.html:1
View_EventDetailsComponent_0 EventDetailsComponent.html:1 proxyClass

Request to access cookie or storage on “http://localhost:4200/” was blocked because we are blocking all storage access requests.
```

**Local Storage Service :**

```
     public getFav(): FavoriteStorage[] {
return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favlist'));

          }
private setLocalStorageFavList(favL: FavoriteStorage[]): void {
    window.localStorage.setItem('favlist', JSON.stringify({ favList: favL }));
  }
```

I've tried localStorage.setItem()/getItem() instead of window.localStorage.setItem() /getItem()

Answer (score 0):

> localStorage is the same as globalStorage[location.hostname], with the
>   exception of being scoped to an HTML5 origin (scheme + hostname +
>   non-standard port)

The old Firefox behavior was buggy, and the bug got fixed. Per spec, setting document.domain should have absolutely no effect on the behavior of localStorage, so in your case, you're trying to set localStorage for a different domain, which is not allowed.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=495337 and the localStorage spec for details.

More you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Privacy/Storage_access_policy)

Comment: I did not get your point - "trying to set localstorage for a different domain ". I'm storing a JSON with **NO** domain name like xxx.xxx.com or yyy.com or zzz.com/image.jpg containing keys or values on my locahost with port :4200. All code is on browser.